# How to return multiple types from a function?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm using [actix_web](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.2.0/actix_web/) for my handlers and I've stumbled across a problem.

I'd like to return a `web::Json` with 1 out of 2 types depending on the parameters.

I have something like this which doesn't compile because `impl` can only be one type

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct TerraformFieldParams {
    field: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct TerraformFieldResponse {
    fieldName: String,
    fieldId: String,
    dataType: String,
    state: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct TerraformFieldErrorResponse {
    error: String,
}

pub async fn handler(params: web::Path<TerraformFieldParams>) -> impl actix_web::Responder {
    match &params.field[..] {
        "0000000006549B31" => web::Json(TerraformFieldResponse {
            fieldName: String::from("host"),
            fieldId: String::from("000000123"),
            dataType: String::from("String"),
            state: String::from("Enabled"),
        }),

        _ => web::Json(TerraformFieldErrorResponse {
            err: String::from("error 123"),
        }),
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: an `enum` wouldn't work?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to return an error, why aren't you using `Result` (https://actix.rs/docs/errors/)?

Comment: As @rethab mentioned, `Result` is the idiomatic Rust solution for returning either a response, or an error. In you case: `-> Result<Json<TerraformFieldResponse>, Json<TerraformFieldErrorResponse>>`

Comment: Actix-web has the [`Either`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.2.0/actix_web/enum.Either.html) responder precisely for this use case.

Comment: So I've ended up first using actix error but then I've noticed that I can use `HttpResponse::build(StatusCode::<STATUS>).json(<serializable_object>)` which is simpler in my case. Anyways, I can't post that because someone closed the question :(